# How to use the Apple Business Connect API?

Tags: documentation, endpoint, apple-maps

I like to keep the data of some locations that I administrate in sync. Currently I have to edit the entries in Google Maps, Bing Maps and Apple Maps each on its own. I know that Google Maps and Apple Maps have an API for this, but I struggle with the API of Apple. There is an documentation for the endpoints of the API but there are two things missing: first I don't know which domain to use, second I don't know how to authorize myself to the API.

Has anyone tried this by himself/herself and can give me a hint how to use the Apple Business Connect API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who like to go on the same journey as me: just don't do it! Apple does not like developers and they said it in many ways.

But for the unteachable ones: the endpoint is `https://businessconnect.apple.com/api`. The documentation is at https://businessconnect.apple.com/docs/data-specification/v1.3/introduction and you can only use it if you have more than a small or medium sized company (you need more than 250 employees).

Just use a tool like Yext for your task or do it the hard way with a headless browser.